# finding critical numbers and abs max value

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have $$g(x)=2x^3-3x^2-12x+1 $$for the interval $$(-2,3). $$
I took the derivative, then put that as $$6(x^2-6x-2)$$
foiled the inside to $$6(x-2)(x+1)$$ then got -2, -1, and 3 as the critical numbers, and plugged them in to get a absolute max of -3, but that's not matching the answer. I don't need a full answer, least I don't want to need one, but could someone give me a hint or point me to which of the steps I messed up on?

Comment: It's not $6(x^2-6x-2)$, but I think you know that because you factored it okay.

Comment: You missed a critical point, however. When is $6(x-2)(x+1)=0$?

Comment: What was your computed value for $g(-1)$? I suspect you need to re-check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute extrema of a function can occur at its critical points or at the endpoints of the interval.  In this case, the interval $(-2, 3) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -2 < x < 3\}$ is open, so the extrema must occur in the interior of the interval.

Since $g(x) = 2x^3 - 3x^2 - 12x + 1$, its derivative is 
\begin{align*}
g'(x) & = 6x^2 - 6x - 12\\
      & = 6(x^2 - x - 2)\\
      & = 6(x^2 - 2x + x - 2)\\
      & = 6[x(x - 2) + 1(x - 2)]\\
      & = 6(x + 1)(x - 2)
\end{align*}
Setting the derivative equal to zero yields the critical points $x = -1$ and $x = 2$.

You can determine whether the critical points are relative maxima or minima by using the First Derivative Test or the Second Derivative Test.

*First Derivative Test*.  Assume $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$ and assume that the derivative $f'$ exists everywhere in the open interval $(a, b)$ except possibly at a point $c$.
(a)  If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x < c$ and $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x > c$, then $f$ has a relative maximum at $c$.
(b)  If $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x < c$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x > c$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $c$.

To apply the First Derivative Test to your problem, note that $f'(-1) = 0$ and $f'(2) = 0$, so we can take $c = -1$ or $c = 2$.  Determine the sign of $f'(x)$ in the intervals $(-2, -1)$, $(-1, 2)$, and $(2, 3)$ by evaluating $f'(x)$ at $-3/2$, $0$, and $5/2$, which is most easily done by considering the equation $f'(x) = 6(x + 1)(x - 2)$ and considering the sign of each factor.

*Second Derivative Test*.   Let $c$ be a cirtical point of $f$ in an open interval $(a, b)$.  Assume also that the second derivative $f''$ exists in $(a, b)$.  Then
(a)  If $f''(x) < 0$ in $(a, b)$, then $f$ has a relative maximum at $c$.
(b)  If $f''(x) > 0$ in $(a, b)$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $c$.

To apply the Second Derivative Test to your problem, differentiate $g(x) = 6x^2 - 6x - 12$ and evaluate the second derivative at $c = -1$ and $c = 2$.  Note that the second derivative changes sign at $x = 1/2$.

Once you determine whether an extremum is a relative maximum or minimum, evaluate the function at the extremum to determine the maximum or minimum value.

Note that if the interval were $[-2, 3] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -2 \leq x \leq 3\}$, you would have to compare the values of $g(-2)$ and $g(3)$ to those of $g(-1)$ and $g(2)$ to determine the absolute maximum and minimum values.